# Unable to insert in localstorage

Tags: extjs, insert, sencha-touch, touch, local-storage

I have model:

```
Ext.define('SizoMag.model.SizoBuscetModel', {  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
fields: [{name: 'text', type: 'string'}, {name: 'price', type: 'string'}],
proxy: {
  type: 'localstorage',
  id  : 'buscetmodel'
 }
}
});
```

and store

```
Ext.define('SizoMag.store.SizoBuscetStore', {extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
 config: {
 storeId: 'SizoBuscetStore'
}
});
```

But when I try to add an entry to the store - get error
[WARN][Ext.data.Operation#setModel] Unless you define your model using metadata, an Operation needs to have a model defined.Console.js:35

[WARN][Ext.data.reader.Reader#process] In order to read record data, a Reader needs to have a Model defined on it. Console.js:35

Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

I add so

```
var store=Ext.getStore('SizoBuscetStore');
store.load();store.add({text:'txt',price:'150'});
store.sync();
```

Please help me/
Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, you need to define a model type for a store so it can configure its reader:

```
Ext.define('SizoMag.store.SizoBuscetStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'SizoBuscetStore',
    model: 'SizoBuscetModel'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey its Simple Try this

in Store:

```
   Ext.define('e4b.store.Adult_DOBStore', {
extend: "Ext.data.Store",

config: {
    model: "e4b.model.Adult_DOBModel",
    autoLoad: true, 
    clearOnPageLoad: false,
}

         });
```

and Your model will be

```
           Ext.define('e4b.model.Adult_DOBModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {

    fields: ['Adult1Date'],


    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id  : 'adultdob'
    }

       }
```

});

And Now in your Contoller...

First Get the Value

```
      var A_select1=Ext.getCmp('select1').getValue();

     localStorage.setItem("Adult1_select1",A_select1); //Assign the value to localstore

   var AdultSalutation={
                    // object                               
 'Adult1_select1':A_select1,

                 };

var AdultSalutationstore =Ext.getStore('Adult_AdultSalutationstore');// cal store 

        AdultSalutationstore.add(AdultSalutation);  // add the oject here
      AdultSalutationstore.sync();
   AdultSalutationstore.load();
```